# How to write a Shell Script to get min max and average value from sar reports

Tags: bash, shell

e.g.

```
02:00:01 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
02:10:01 PM     all     28.78      0.00     12.62     11.21      0.64     46.75
02:20:01 PM     all     26.28      0.00      9.84     12.62      0.46     50.80
02:30:01 PM     all     28.26      0.00      8.45     11.06      0.46     51.77
02:40:01 PM     all     18.89      0.00      5.88      9.00      0.19     66.04
02:50:01 PM     all     27.32      0.00      7.65      8.72      0.33     55.98
03:00:01 PM     all     23.56      0.00      7.54     14.35      0.21     54.33
03:10:01 PM     all     26.38      0.00     11.59     12.18      0.95     48.90
```

I want to write a shell script which fetches min max and avg values for a day from this report for Memory and CPU Utilization and schedule it in a crontab.

Comment: free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }' this gives me avg memory but i want minimum and maximum values too for memory and cpu utilization

Comment: Start by switching from shell to a language intended for data processing.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can do this. Example to compute the average of `user` column (fourth column):

```
tail -n +2 data.txt | awk '{n += 1; user += $4} END {printf("%lf\n", user / n)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

scriptfile:

```
NR == 1 {
    tit=$8
} 
NR > 1 {
        tot+=$8
        if ( $8 > max ) {
                max=$8
        }
        if ( NR == 2 ) {
                min = $8
        }
        else if ( $8 < min ) {
                min = $8
        }
}
END {
        avg=tot/(NR-1)
        print tit"=====total - "tot" max - "max" min - "min" average - "avg
}
```

Then run:

```
awk -f scriptfile filename
```

Output:

```
%steal=====total - 3.24 max - 0.95 min - 0.19 average - 0.462857
```

In the awk script we ignore the first line by stipulating number record greater than 1. Then we set the min, max and total values. When the number record is one, we use the data to set a title. At the end of the file, we work out the average total.

The script in this example looks at %steal (the 8th space delimited field) but it can of course be modified depending on the column we are concerned with.

Comment: I am getting error as line 4: NR: command not found
 line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
 line 7: `}'

Comment: awk -f scriptfile filename is giving output it is keep on running tell me any other to execute it

Comment: What version of awk are you running? awk --version

Comment: I am using AWK 3.1.7

Comment: It works on gawk and mawk, not sure about standard awk though.